# Robustly retrieve which field caued 'duplicate key error' in Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So, mongo throws an error-message such as the following on code 11000 or 11001:

```
{ [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: mean-dev.users.$username_1  dup key: { : "asdasd" }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: mean-dev.users.$username_1  dup key: { : "asdasd" }',
  code: 11000,
  n: 0,
  connectionId: 718,
  ok: 1 }
```

Right now, I'm parsing the error-message to retrieve which field has a duplicate key, which is incredibly dirty. i.e: I don't want to test all kinds of duplicate errors on different indices (multikey, compound, etc) to see if this parser still works.

Any helpers in Node that I could use, that let me robustly retrieve the offending field for such errors?

Comment: Don't think so, AFAIK the `mongodb` driver passes the error generated by the server as-is (and server commands for getting the last error, like `db.getLastErrorObj()`, aren't of much help either).

Comment: The values should be easy to work out.  You probably want the db/collection name, index name, and the offending duplicate key. `dup_key` is the offending duplicate value. You can split the namespace on `$`; the left portion will be the db.collection name and the right portion the index name. So "mean-dev.users.$username_1" => "mean-dev.users" (db.collection), "username_1" (index name).

Comment: @stennie: problem is going from indexname to keyname. Is indexname always derived from key and how is this done for multivalued or compound indices. That's the 'robustness' , or lack thereof, i was referring to

Comment: By default the [index name is derived](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/) by concatenating the keys and the sort order. For example, "{ name: 1, created: -1 }" becomes `name_1_created_-1`. However, it is possible to assign a name when the index is created (which for your purposes could perhaps be a more meaningful label).

Comment: It's absolutely nonsense to rely on parsing a string for this. There's no reason why mongodb (or the nodejs driver) wouldn't return a more useful structure. If I relied on this, I'd be fearful of updating to even a new minor version because my code could be broken. So I'll have to do an integration tests for it... idiotic.

Comment: If you're for getting this fixed, please vote this issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4637

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the actual keys for an index, rather than parsing an unreliable string, you can simply query the system.indexes collection like this:

```
db.collection('system.indexes').findOne({ ns: 'mean-dev.users', name: 'username_1' }, cb);
```

Which should result in a document containing a key object, listing of all the field names that make up this index key, e.g.:

```
{
  v: 1,
  ns: 'mean-dev.users',
  name: 'username_1',
  key: {
    username: 1
  }
}
```