# How to get which @Indexed(unique=true) is failed in spring-data-mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, exception, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using `Spring-Boot 1.5.1` and `MongoDB 3.4.6`

I've a `MongoDB` document which has some `@Indexed(unique=true)` annotation on some field.

```
@Document(collection="Product")
public class Product{
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String name;
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String searchName;
```

When there is any duplicate name or searchName it throws `org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException`.

Stacktrace :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: E11000 duplicate key error index: Product.name  dup key: { : "name" }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: E11000 duplicate key error index: Product.name dup key: { : "name" }
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:52)
```

How can we get the key on which the the exception was thrown.

Something like when we put `@NotNull(message = "Product briefDescription cannot be null")` on some filed and it gives you the `message` in the `exception`, but there is no `message` attribute for `@Indexed` annotation.

Any way to do it?

Comment: it would be good if you could put some more of the Exception stack trace.. Usually, it is written in the stackTrace.

Comment: @KaustubhKallianpur Added.

Comment: so u want to know on which key the duplicate exception is thrown and use it for further? according to the stacktrace, E11000 already exists as Name  in the database, which has thrown the exception. Its not the searchName field.

Comment: Do you want to field name or do you want to value of field which break uniqueness?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exception message has the information that you're asking for, it includes both the name of the index for which the error was thrown (in your case `Product.name` or `Product.searchName`).

Unfortunately you'll have to parse that information out of the message. This limitation has been raised elsewhere:

[Robustly retrieve which field caued 'duplicate key error' in Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890057/robustly-retrieve-which-field-caued-duplicate-key-error-in-mongo)

And in the following JIRA tickets:

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4637
- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19281

However, in your example (with the duplicate being the null), I would strongly suggest that you push as much validation as possible down at the client level and not rely on the database to handle any validations that can be done at the client.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't get the key of the duplicate document directly in the error as it's not a core functionality of the Mongo driver. Your best bet would probably be to do a find operation on your collection if the duplicate key exception is raised. You might consider opening a ticket on the [Mongo Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) to see if the dev team is interested in adding such a functionality in the future though.

Answer (score 0):

discover operation on your accumulation if the copy key special case is raised.
On the off chance that you need to see the genuine keys for a record,query the system.indexes like:

```
db.collection('system.indexes').findOne({ ns: 'mean-dev.users', name: 'username_1' }, cb);
```